# Inconsistent Click and Menu Access Using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I use the following code to open a menu and then click on an item on the menu. It works fine the majority of the time but occasionally it throws the following error. Is there a better way to interact with this menu and not receive an error inconsistantly:

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not
> interactable:
>
> has no size and location   (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.125)

My code is below.

```
            // Move to and click Manage Users button / dropdown 
            Actions actions4 = new Actions(driver);
            actions4.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                    "//*[@id=\"ja-content\"]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/div/button")))
            .click().perform();
            
            // Move to and click on View User
            actions4.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                    "//*[@id=\"ja-content\"]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/div/ul/li[1]/a")))
            .click().perform();
```

The menu I am interacting with is below.

[image]

Source code for the initial button being interacted with:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Manage User&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of locating the element with `driver.findElement` try changing it to `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator))` so that your code will be as following:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 30);
// Move to and click Manage Users button / dropdown 
Actions actions4 = new Actions(driver);
actions4.moveToElement(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(
                    "//*[@id=\"ja-content\"]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/div/button")))).click().perform();
            
// Move to and click on View User
actions4.moveToElement(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(
                    "//*[@id=\"ja-content\"]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/div/ul/li[1]/a")))).click().perform();
```

Also I would recomend you to improve your locators. They are too long and breakable.
Also maybe you do not need to perform click with Actions, it can be done with regular Selenium click since lements are clickable? However I'm not sure about this. It depends on the actual page you working on.

Comment: When you say improve the locators, what / how do you mean? Thanks! Am just trying out your solution now.

Comment: You need to learn how to create good locators. There are a lot of tutorials about this. I can't advice about something specific since I learnt this several years ago. But generally locator should be based on the element's attribute like class name value or any other attribute value, often it will be based also on some parent element, but in 98% cases it will be based on no more than 2 elements while your locators are binding together 17-19 elements where all of them are exactly direct child of the previous. Such locators are extremelly inreliable and breakable.

Comment: Unfortunately I now get a timeout exception. The page is loaded but then the menu is not interacted with as the timeout occurs. Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@id="ja-content"]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/div/ul/li[1]/a (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

Comment: I hope you set not too short timeout? Maybe you need to scroll that element into the view? Actually I need to see all your code including the link to the page you working on in order to see what is going on there...